# Cannot subscript a value of type 'Self' with an index of type 'Int'

Tags: swift

I keep getting the following error when trying to extend `Collection` in Swift:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Self' with an index of type 'Int'

Here is my code:

```
extension Collection {
    func random() -> Element {
        let randomIndex = count.arc4random
        return self[randomIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subscript` method of `Collection` needs a `Self.Index`, not an `Int`.

You need:

```
return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: randomIndex)]
```

Comment: don't forget the `isEmpty` check. just to be safe

Comment: @staticVoidMan That would be a good enhancement to the OP method. But it also means their `random` method needs to return an optional `Element`.

Comment: @staticVoidMan the way I use it in my code, there should never be an empty collection. Since this is the case, would it be best to add an `assert(count > 0, "Collection must not be empty")` statement in my extension?

Comment: `assert(!isEmpty, "...")`.